# Chef on AWS - ERROR: Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: AuthFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

Chef Workstation and Server is setup on AWS as follows:

Chef Development Kit Version: 0.10.0,
Chef-server 12.2,
chef-client version: 12.5

This setup has been working for around an year.
Today, got following error when creating ec2 instance by executing'knife ec2 server create' command on chef-workstation.
**ERROR: Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: AuthFailure => AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials**

There is no change in aws auth keys or file permissions. I'm not able to understand why this error all of sudden?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Is your workstation time ok ? If there's a drift between the machine running knife and AWS of more than 5 mins the failure arise. If you don't have NTP activated on this machine you should set it up.

Comment: Both are ec2 instances in same region/zone  and their timestamp matches.

Comment: The error comes from Amazon API servers, not from your machines. Just set up ntp and have them synced with the world. If your credentials didn't change that the only reason AWS API servers will deny access.

Comment: Amazon probably changed something, all the versions of things you mention are over a year old. Upgrade and try again.